# Is it possible to speed this recursive directory method up?

Tags: c#

I am listing all directories in a console app, but it takes forever, more than 10+ minutes (just assuming here, it probably took more than 10 minutes), I know there are a ton of directories, but is 10+ minutes too long to begin with?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DirSearch(@"c:\");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void DirSearch(string sDir)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(d);
                    DirSearch(d);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception excpt)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Debug build instead of Release?

Comment: Isn't most of that time just spent writing them to the console? If you remove that line, isn't it instantaneous.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes - don't make it recursive manually. This is built in, you can use `SearchOption.AllDirectories` to include all subdirectories in your search:

```
foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    Console.WriteLine(d);
}
```

Or alternatively use [`Directory.EnumerateDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383462.aspx) which yields directory names as it finds them instead of putting all of them in an array first:

```
foreach (string d in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(sDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    Console.WriteLine(d);
}
```

Comment: This appears to be missing a SearchPattern param.  When I do:Directory.GetDirectories(sDir,"*", SearchOption.AllDirectories), nothing shows up.

Comment: I guess Directory.GetDirectories still takes a while because as you said, it puts it into an array list first before it starts enumerating them, hence, your suggestion of EnumerateDirectories, correct?

Comment: I keep getting an access path denied, but instead of continuing, it halts the execution of the program.  This only happens when I do a directories.Count(), it will list the directory names without the Count(), but once I reach the folder that I can't access, instead of skipping over it, it halts execution.

Comment: It still takes a very long time even without recursion because I have probably almost 1 million directories or more.  This is probably due to all those TFS branches I created.